# What is preventing this constexpr to be evaluated at compile time?

Tags: c++, c++11, template-meta-programming, constexpr

Considering the following code:

```
#include <unordered_set>
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstring>

constexpr auto cstring_hash(const char* istring) -> size_t {
    return (*istring) == '\0' ?
        size_t(0):
        (*istring) + cstring_hash(istring + 1);
}

constexpr auto cstring_length(const char* istring) -> size_t {
    return (*istring) == '\0' ?
        size_t(0):
        size_t(1) + cstring_length(istring + 1);
}

class PrehashedString {
public:
    constexpr PrehashedString(const char* istring) 
    : str_(istring)
    , hash_(cstring_hash(istring))
    , size_(cstring_length(istring)) {
    }
    constexpr auto& get_hash() const { return hash_; }
    auto operator==(const PrehashedString& iother) const {
        return 
            size_ == iother.size_ &&
            std::strcmp(str_, iother.str_) == 0;
    }
private:
    const char* str_;
    size_t hash_;
    size_t size_;
};

namespace std {
template <>
struct hash<PrehashedString> {
constexpr auto operator()(const PrehashedString& ihashed_string) const -> size_t {
    return ihashed_string.get_hash();
}
};
}
```

How come the `hash0` (where `str0` is created by *value*) gets evaluated at runtime while `hash1` (where `str1` is created by *reference*) get evaluated at compile time? 
I've tried it in both *MSVC* and *GCC 6.2/7.0* and it seems they both fail. Is it something in the standard which prevents it to be evaluated at compile time?

```
auto func0() {
  const auto str0 = PrehashedString("my_string_0");
  const auto hash0 = str0.get_hash();

  const auto& str1 = PrehashedString("my_string_1");
  const auto hash1 = str1.get_hash();

  return hash0 + hash1;
}
```

Expanding it further, how can I force this to evaluate at compile time with a constexpr function:

```
auto func1(std::unordered_set<PrehashedString>& iset) {
  return iset.count("my_key");
}
```

**Note:**
I am aware how to achieve this by making the constructor only accept string literals `(template <size_t N> PrehashedString(const char (&istring)[N]){...})`, and utilizing the string literal length as a template parameter for the hash function, I'm just curious in why it fails.

Comment: Try adding a constexpr copy ctor.

Comment: I tried clang 3.9.0 and it is able to do everything in compile time.

Comment: I got reversed result, `hash0` at compile time but not `hash1` [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/556b70d7f6990620)

Comment: I've tried constexpr copy-constructors etc, but it still doesn't help in the unordered_set case.

Comment: Do you really need [tag:C++11]?  `constexpr` gets much less annoying and restricted in [tag:C++14], you can write more natural code.  Second, I doubt `unordered_set` can be `constexpr` as it does memory allocation?  And `new` is not `constexpr`?

Comment: @Yakk: As noted at the end, it works with the unordered_set if I construct it with a string literal, and utilize a templated version of cstring_hash taking length as a template parameter. On your first question, I'm just used to C++11 constexpr.